# Get latest backbone model with rails without refreshing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I am using backbone.js for creating a SPA. My application runs on rails. My problem is whenever my SPA does anything that interacts with my rails controller and changes the rails model, the immediate change is not refelected on my backbone model. I can however refresh the page and the backbone model gets updated.

My model is 'user'. So this is what i am doing in my users_controller:

```
render :json => @user.reload.info
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to poll new data every `X` seconds (using `model.fetch()` and `setInterval`)
You can also decide to use [socket.io](http://socket.io/) with a backbone [plugin](https://github.com/scttnlsn/backbone.io)

and you view should listen to the model changes when they occur